# Start filebeat using a Java code?

Tags: java, powershell, processbuilder, filebeat

I'm using filebeat to read some log files and I need to start filebeat using a Java program. And the filebeat commands are executed using the Windows PowerShell. I used the following code but it didn't work.

```java
try {
    ProcessBuilder b1 = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\" && ./filebeat -e -c filebeat.yml -d \"publish\"\\");
    b1.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p1 = b1.start();
    BufferedReader r1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
    String line1;
    while (true) {
        line1 = r1.readLine();
        if (line1 == null) { break; }
        System.out.println(line1);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Try this: `"powershell.exe /c \"C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\filebeat.exe" -e -c \"C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\\filebeat.yml\""`

Comment: Great. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code worked.

```
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\\filebeat.exe", "-c", "C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\\filebeat.yml", "-e");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();

        BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
        }
        p.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing [PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help) with [CMD](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771320.aspx). The latter has a parameter `/c`, the former doesn't. Also, instead of using `cd` in the comandline you should simply set the working directory on the `ProcessBuilder` object, and each token of your commandline should be a separate array element.

Change your code to something like this and it should do what you expect:

```java
ProcessBuilder b1 = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "filebeat", "-e", "-c", "filebeat.yml", "-d", "\"publish\"");
b1.directory(new File("C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat"));
b1.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p1 = b1.start();
```

Comment: When I used the above code the compiler shows an error like this. "The method directory(File) in the type ProcessBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (String)".

Comment: Apparently `directory()` expects a `File` object. See updated answer.